# EntityFramework Include Without Guarantee of Existence

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have an issue I am unsure how to solve. I have three models, similar to as follows.

```
public class Parent : BaseEntity {
  [Key]
  public string Guid { get; set; }
  
  [NotMapped]
  public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child : BaseEntity {
  [Key]
  public string Guid { get; set; }

  public string ParentGuid { get; set; }

  public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail : BaseEntity {
  [Key]
  public string Guid { get; set; }
  
  [ForeignKey(nameof(Child))]
  public string ChildGuid { get; set; }
  public Child Child { get; set }
}
```

I'm attempting to include both the children and the details. However, I am not guaranteed the Guid on the child exists in the parent table. That's why I went with NotMapped, but am willing and able to change that if need be. Right now I have this:

```
query.GroupJoin(context.Parents,
                          parent => parent.ChildGuid,
                          child => child.Guid,
                          (parent, childs) => new
                          {
                              Parent = parent,
                              Childs = childs
                          }
                        )
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(combos =>
                        {
                            combos.Parent.Childs = combos.Childs.ToList();
                            return combos.Parent;
                        })
                        .AsQueryable();
```

But that, of course, does not include the Details. Not sure if I'm heading the right direction here or not, but could use some direction if anyone has run into this before.

Answer (score 0):

A typical parent-child relationship has the ParentID on the child table/entity. Your entity definitions seem to reflect that, but then your Linq expression refers to some parent.ChildGuid that isn't mentioned in your entity.

First let's correct your entity definition relationships. Childs shouldn't be excluded. A parent can have 0 or multiple children. Collections should be declared as `virtual ICollection<T>` rather than concrete `List<T>`. `virtual` enables lazy loading and helps ensure that EF proxies are fully functional for tracking changes of items in the collections. We should also initialize those collections with a new concrete list. This helps ensure that any new entity we create is ready to go accepting children.

```
public class Parent : BaseEntity 
{
  [Key]
  public string Guid { get; set; }
  
  public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}

public class Child : BaseEntity 
{
  [Key]
  public string Guid { get; set; }

  public string ParentGuid { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; } = new List<Detail>();
}

public class Detail : BaseEntity 
{
  [Key]
  public string Guid { get; set; }
  
  [ForeignKey(nameof(Child))]
  public string ChildGuid { get; set; }
  public virtual Child Child { get; set }
}
```

EF can automatically map relationships provided you follow supported conventions in your naming. Chances are with the "Guid" syntax for your ID columns, EF won't work these out automatically so you will probably need to give it some help through configuration. For example in the OnModelCreating of the DbContext:

```
// EF Core
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Childs)
    .WithOne()
    .IsRequired() // If a Child must have a ParentGuid
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentGuid);
```

Since Child has a ParentGuid but no Parent reference declared, we use the `WithOne()` with no mapping, then use the `HasForeignKey` to set up the relationship. Similarly we set up the relationship between Child and Details:

```
// EF Core
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Details)
    .WithOne(x => x.Child)
    .IsRequired() // If a Detail must have a Child
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ChildGuid);
```

In this case since we have a Child reference on Detail so we map to that.

Now regarding this statement:

> However, I am not guaranteed the Guid on the child exists in the parent table.

From this it somewhat implies that a ParentGuid on the Child table might not exist in the Parents table. This would be a fairly serious concern from a database normalization and ensuring a valid data state. I would highly recommend to avoid trying to use a non-normalized schema such as attempting to "share" a Child table between multiple Parent tables. A classic example where this is tried is having an Address table (Child) referencing a ParentId that could point at a Customer (Parent) or Site (Parent) and/or other parent-like tables. Instead, you should consider a more normalized approach which would use a CustomerAddress and SiteAddress etc. linking table to ensure these relationships can be mapped out.

If a Child can exist without a Parent then you just need to remove the `.IsRequired()`.

Now when querying, you don't need to worry specifically about joining and grouping, just query through the navigation properties and either eager-load the related data you want when working with the Entity graph, or project the data using `Select` when querying for details:

```
var query = context.Parents
    .Include(x => x.Childs)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Details)
```

To get the children with their associated Parent:

```
var query = context.Parents
    .Include(x => x.Childs)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Details)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Childs.Select(c => new {Parent = x, Child = c})
    .ToList();
```

If you want to include children that have no parent:

```
var query = context.Parents
    .Include(x => x.Childs)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Details)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Childs.Select(c => new {Parent = x, Child = c})
    .Union(context.Childs.Where(x => x.ParentGuid == null))
    .ToList();
```

These are very rough guesses as the type of query you want to perform. Again, if the ParentGuid could be referring to a non-existent row in the DB or a different table I would really look at correcting that to ensure the data maintains referential integrity. I don't recommend trying to "break" EF behavior to work with an effectively broken schema. You may get it to have a semblance of working, but it could very easily lead to exceptions or unexpected behaviour.